# sorting function in python for algorithms and data structures

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, sorting

Hi I have to write a function that returns input number of x digits in acceding order. (x <= 10^9). First we should input number of digits, then the actual digits.
eg-

input->

```
3
-3 4 2
```

output ->

```
-3 2 4
```

here is my code. For smaller amounts of x code is correct but for larger amounts I get time limit exceeded.(time limit is 1s)

```
def Sort(alist):
    for passnum in range(len(alist)-1, 0, -1):
        for i in range(passnum):
            if alist[i] > alist[i + 1]:
                temp = alist[i]
                alist[i] = alist[i + 1]
                alist[i + 1] = temp
    return alist


x = int(input())
if x == 0:
    print()
else:
    y = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
    for i in range(x):
        print(Sort(y)[i], end=' ')
```

Comment: Copy and paste all your code into the question, select it all again and hit ctrl-k to format it

Comment: Hi, I edited the post. If it is still unclear please say.

Answer (score 1):

```
print(str(sorted(map(int,input().split()))).replace(',', '')[1:-1])
```

This gives you output what you are expecting.
Input: -3 4 2
Output: -3 2 4

Input: -3 8 5 -1 2 4 6
Output: -3 -1 2 4 5 6 8

Comment: The monster does work, however, it seems to be very well obfuscated and not entirely clear what that does at a glance. The OP clearly doesn't operate on the same level of Python-fu.

Comment: @ferrix Sorry, I'm not sure of Python-fu. I can split the above code and add here. map(int,input().split()) takes input with space as delimiter. Then I have sorted it using sorted() as sorted(map(int,input().split())). Then, I have converted it to string using str() as str(sorted(map(int,input().split()))) . So if we give input as -3 4 2 the output will be as '[-3, 2, 4]'. As there should not be any comma in the output, I have replaced comma with space using replace() method of string. I used [1:-1] to remove "[" and "]".

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten your code quite a bit:

```
_ = input() # does not matter

print(sorted(map(int,input().strip().split()), sep=" ")
```